# Displaying Reports on SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

First of all, I must say that I'm new to this. I'm a 3rd year ICT & Business student and an intern in a international company. My assignment is to create a reporting service on the company's intranet (SharePoint).

The company wants to have a section on the intranet where only managers can access. To give you an idea, lets say one of the managers wants a report like this:

"Show the names of the male interns who worked between 2012 – 2013".

And lets say the interface on the intranet is going to be like the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQLOy.jpg

Once the manager fills in the required fields and presses the button;
 1.SharePoint is going to create the query, 
2.SharePoint is going to ask for the data which is stored in the SQL Server,
 3.SQL Server is going to send the data to SharePoint,
 4.SharePoint is going to create an Excel File.

In order to achieve such a reporting system, where and how do you suggest me to start? Any links, guides etc. would be much appretiated. Even a general response would help me to understand the basics.

NOTE: Our IT department will handle the connections between the SharePoint and SQL server. I don't have to worry about that. All I need is to find out how you create a query on Sharepoint which will connect to SQL server and ask for data and display it on SharePoint (or Excel in this case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried CAML Query

Comment: You can use Sharepoint Designer to Create query for  what is in the SPList

Comment: I don't want to query the SharePoint Lists (which both of your suggestions refers to). I want to query the data which is stored in a SQL server and display it on SharePoint.

Comment: You probably need to ask your IT department what they are using as the connector between Sharepoint and SQL server to start with, if they are using SQL Reporting Services in Sharepoint Integrated mode, your approach would be quite different to if they have done something more custom.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already, you need to use SharePoint Designer.
Create a new site in SharePoint.  You'll need to manage the permissions as to prevent non-management from accessing the new site.
Open the new site in SP Designer.  Bring up the Data Source Library (Data View > Manage Data Sources).  There you can 'Connect to a database...'.  I can't help you there.  For this you'll need the DB connection string and you'll have to design a query that gets a super set of interns (to your example).  You can then use filters to extract the specific intern.  This also will take some exploring on your part.
You may be able to customize the SQL query using form elements but I haven't seen that done before.  Typically the DB connection pulls down a data table and that is consumed by the web parts on the page.

Hope this at least gets you started...